# Verify solution: Is this gradient correct?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, special-functions

So I want to calculate minus the gradient of $$\Phi_1=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)r^{l}P_l(\cos(\theta))$$
where $P_n$ is the $n$-th Legendre polynomial
then we have $$-\nabla \Phi_1=-\left(\begin{array}{c}\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}f(l)\cdot l \cdot r^{l-1}P_l(\cos(\theta)\\ -\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)\cdot (l+1) \cdot r^{l-1}\frac{\cos(\theta)P_n(\cos(\theta))-P_{n-1}(\cos(\theta))}{\sin(\theta)}\end{array}\right)?$$

Or is it rather: $$-\nabla \Phi_1=-\left(\begin{array}{c}\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}f(l)\cdot l \cdot r^{l-1}P_l(\cos(\theta))\\ 
\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}f(l)\cdot l \cdot r^{l-1}\frac{\cos(\theta)P_n(\cos(\theta))-P_{n-1}(\cos(\theta))}{\sin(\theta)}\end{array}\right)$$

Notice that the only change that there is, is in the second component, the first might be right. $f$ is a function that does neither depend on $r$ nor does it depend on $\theta$.

Comment: are there any problems witht the excercise?

Comment: Is this an atomic physics problem?

Comment: yes, how did you know?

Comment: I read a small atomic physics book about 4 years ago.

Comment: Do you mean Legendre Polynomial in place of Legendre Symbol?

Comment: @MathPhysUG Of course.

Comment: The main problem here is to find $$\frac{\partial P_{\ell}(\cos \theta)}{\partial\theta}$$

Comment: Sure, sorry I meant legendre polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x=\cos\theta$ and $\Phi_1=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)r^{l}P_l(x(\theta))$

Then $-\nabla\Phi_1= -\left({\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial r },{1 \over r}{\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial \theta }\right)=-\left({\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial r },{1 \over r}{\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial x }{ dx \over d \theta }\right)$
$${\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial r}=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)lr^{l-1}P_l(\cos(\theta))$$

According to [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+legendre+polynomial#_=_):
$${\partial P_l \over \partial x} = {-(l+1) (x P_l(x)-P_{l+1}(x)) \over (x^2-1)}$$

So, $${\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial x }=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)r^{l}\left({-(l+1) (x P_l(x)-P_{l+1}(x)) \over (x^2-1)}\right)$$

Then,$${1 \over r}{\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial \theta }={1 \over r}{\partial \Phi_1 \over \partial x }{ dx \over d \theta }=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}f(l)r^{l-1}\left(-{(l+1) (\cos\theta P_l(\cos\theta)-P_{l+1}(\cos\theta)) \over (\cos^2\theta-1)}\right)\cdot(-\sin\theta)$$
$$ =\sum_{l=0}^{\infty}-{(l+1)f(l)r^{l-1} (\cos\theta P_l(\cos\theta)-P_{l+1}(\cos\theta)) \over \sin\theta}$$

Finally,
$$-\nabla\Phi_1=-\left(\begin{array}{c} \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}f(l)lr^{l-1}P_l(\cos(\theta))\\\ \sum_{l=1}^{\infty}-{(l+1)f(l)r^{l-1} (\cos\theta P_l(\cos\theta)-P_{l+1}(\cos\theta)) \over \sin\theta}\end{array}\right)$$

Hope that helps.

Comment: I think you definitely missed, that the gradient in this coordinates has a $\frac{1}{r}$ term in the second component

Comment: Should it have a $r^{-1}$ term in the second component?
The $r^{-1}$ term in the first component comes from the derivative w.r.t $r$. The $r$ in the second component should be constant as the derivative is w.r.t $\theta$ and it wasn't assumed that $r=r(\theta)$. I could be wrong.

Comment: here it says that the gradient has a $r^{-1}$ term: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: Yes, completely forgot about that $r^{-1}$. I'll correct it.